# In principle I know what GNOME shell is. Can I delete multiple instances of it?

Tags: gnome, ram

**Preface**

This question regards Gnome [1]. Before proceeding any further, the reader should understand what Gnome is. One answer to this question, which is posted below by Henning Kockerbeck, suggest that I should look at a website to understand what Gnome is. Let me be clear, after getting 5 down votes, I went to Gnome.org. In my humble opinion, there is nothing there that spells out in simple terms what Gnome actually is. My best guess is that Gnome is not one thing at all, but rather several. Gnome appears to be a foundation; an amalgam of technologies [2] with which to use the Linux operating system; and a shell called *GNOME shell*. The latter is probably what is referred to by the applications *gnome-3-38-2004* and *gnome-42-2204* (see below).

Further, as suggested below, a more useful account can be obtained by Wikipedia [3]. There it states that,

> GNOME Shell is the graphical shell of the GNOME desktop environment.... It provides basic functions like launching applications, switching between windows and is also a widget engine.

This quote is important to the question at hand because it appears---indeed---that this question is better rewritten as *In principle I know what GNOME shell is; can I delete multiple instances of it?*

**Context**

In a previous question [10], I asked about removing var and usr directories. The motivation was because I kept getting messages about low disk space in my root.  In answer, Merilyn Ne referenced [20], which offers 10 Ways to Clean up Your
Ubuntu System to Free up Disk Space. Item 2 of 10 on the list is to removed remove unused applications. When I look at the list of installed applications, I do not know what some of them are and if I need them, or not.

**Questions**

(1) Can gnome be safely removed?

(2) If there are more than two gnome installed (e.g., gnome-3-38-2004 [362 MB] and gnome-42-2204 [430 MB]) can one, or both, be safely removed?

**References**

[1] https://www.gnome.org/

[2] https://www.gnome.org/technologies/

[3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell

[10] [should I delete var or usr directories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1433975/should-i-delete-var-or-usr-directories)

[20] https://fostips.com/clean-up-ubuntu-free-disk-space/

Comment: @Nmath, I understand how come you feel I might have misconstrued. I was simply using this an an opportunity to learn, but more so to try to get at the lowest hanging fruit before I embark on a significant technical challenge, which is what resizing the partition is for me.  I am now working to figure out how to resize. Separately, I have no idea how these partitions were ever even created, or what they are or are not. For me, and many others, this is all very complicated and even a bit overwhelming.

Comment: I suggest that you reinstall in that case. You should correct the actual problem. This is like building a house on a foundation of quicksand. Any solution that does not resolve the insufficient size of the root partition is untenable and unsustainable

Comment: @NMath, this is a good analogy. A triad of questions to close out this question. (1) Will I actually be asked during the installation of Ubuntu LTS how much I want my root size to be?  (2) Does 25 GB * 1.5 = 38 GB sound reasonable (especially since I have a 256 GB) disk. (3) I have a Thinkpad, and I am concerned about drivers. Is there something I can do to make sure my drivers are on hand for installation.

Comment: @MichaelLevy why bother with partitions? Use the whole boot disk for /. If you have 2 disk use the 2nd for your personal files. Hmmm I also would like to suggest reading up on how AU works. Comments are for improving a question or an answer. Not for chatting. For that we have https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your desktop
- What do you consider "safe"? If you remove it you do not have a desktop and any related software is going to get deleted. You then have a server. Still a working machine so ... in that regard the answer is yes. You can then still install another desktop.
- Those 2 look like snaps. So yes you could delete one of them.

  ```
  sudo snap remove gnome-3-38-2004
  ```

  or

  ```
  sudo snap remove gnome-42-2204
  ```

  Use `sudo snap install gnome-42-2204` (or  `gnome-3-38-2004`) to install it again. Which one is up to you. The one with a 3 will be gnome-3 and the other one normal gnome (log out and check the names of the desktops you can log into; it will list several).

But you will not gain a lot of free space. 430 Mb is nothing. Why not fix it once and for all: increase your root by shrinking another (data) partition?  Removing base software is NOT going to make a dent in your free space. I would suggest to find out on filenames what is eating up space; not based on directories.

If you remove `sudo rm /var/log/*[0-9] /var/log/*gz` you might end up with more free space than by removing one of the gnome snaps.

Comment: possibly some snap apps depend on one version of gnome or the other?

Comment: @Esther those 2 are  Wayland (gnome-3) and fallback to X. so not really dependent. Not sure if I consider it a good idea to remove them but that is just an opinion ;-)

Comment: Oh snap! … congratulations BTW :-)

Answer (score 2):

[GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) is a desktop environment (DE) for Linux. Ubuntu uses GNOME as its default graphical user interface (GUI), but there are other GUIs and DEs you can use alternatively, from [KDEs plasma desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KDE) to more classical DEs like [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) or explicitely small GUIs like [LXDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE) or [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce).

Basically, GNOME and the others I mentioned are responsible for giving you a mouse pointer, windows, buttons, menus, icons, the whole graphic user interface. If you're using another DE than GNOME (or don't want a graphical interface at all), then you can theoretically remove GNOME. But if you're so low on ressources, maybe the "main flavor" of Ubuntu isn't right for you machine, and you might want to look at something like [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) or [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/).

And as a general remark: Ubuntu comes with several thousand software packages you can install, plus the packages from third-party repositories. Please don't ask a question for each of those whether or not you can remove it ;) In most cases, the project homepage of the software in question gives you an idea of what it is and what it does, sometimes even Wikipedia (as we've seen above). If there's still something you don't understand after you tried to find it out for yourself, by all means please ask. But so far, it feels at least to me like you're expecting to be spoon-feed.